# Want to run .sh Linux shell Scripting to rename file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, batch-file

I would like to run a .sh script to rename a file which is in the directory `desktop/reports/don` of my computer. An example of what I need is to rename:

```
TACOS_2013-Jan-22__00-50-00_UTC.csv
```

to

```
TACOS_20130122_005000.csv
```

I have the following script which was created using windows batch script(.bat file). I would like to convert this into linux shell script.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.-" %%A in ('dir /B TACOS_*') do (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  call :getmonth %%B
  ren TACOS*_*%%A-%%B-%%C*_*%%D-%%E-%%F_UTC.csv TACOS_%%A!mon!%%C_%%D%%E%%F.csv
  endlocal
)


:getmonth
if "%1" equ "Jan" set mon=01
if "%1" equ "Feb" set mon=02
if "%1" equ "Mar" set mon=03
if "%1" equ "Apr" set mon=04
if "%1" equ "May" set mon=05
if "%1" equ "Jun" set mon=06
if "%1" equ "Jul" set mon=07
if "%1" equ "Aug" set mon=08
if "%1" equ "Sep" set mon=09
if "%1" equ "Oct" set mon=10
if "%1" equ "Nov" set mon=11
if "%1" equ "Dec" set mon=12
goto :eof
endlocal
```

this is what i have done so far..Please help

```
#!/bin/bash
month["Jan"]=01
month["Feb"]=02
month["Mar"]=03
month["Apr"]=04
month["May"]=05
month["Jun"]=06
month["Jul"]=07
month["Aug"]=08
month["Sep"]=09
month["Oct"]=10
month["Nov"]=11
month["Dec"]=12

directory="desktop/reports/Don/"
for path in "${directory}TACOS_"*; do

    path=${path#${directory}}
    newpath=${path:0:10}${month[${path:11:3}]}${path:15:2}
    newpath=${newpath}__$(tr -d '-' <<< ${path:19:8}).csv

    echo "${directory}${path}" "${directory}${newpath}" # Run this one first!!!
    # mv "YOUR/PATH/${path}" "YOUR/PATH/${newpath}"
done
```

Comment: What does exactly means "couldnt make the script work on linux" ? What are the errors ? Better ask in English what you try to accomplish... bash is not an imaginary shell language, there's some rules to read/learn.

Comment: Don't copy-paste BAT into SH. Instead write it from scratch by accomplishing the necessary iterative renaming bit by bit.

Comment: i didnt copy the code.. i rewrote it completely using all the knowledge i had about shell scripting (not much that i know)... when i saved the script into TACOS.sh and tried running it on my MAC TERMINAL it gives me Permission Denied error

Comment: i removed the permission denied error using chmod u+x but now i get /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.... PLease help

Comment: Don't convert the script. Read more documentation about Linux shell, maybe consider learning scripting languages (e.g. Python), and write the script on Linux from its specification. BTW, I would guess that playing with weird options of `date` could help. Learn about shell functions (you'll probably need to write some, if using `bash`). Read http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ even if it can be criticized.

Comment: i got most of it done just getting two errors

Line 22: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"'
Line 24: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Your tests should be at least `if [ "$1" = "Jan" ]; then mon=01 fi` but you should rather do a `case "$1"`

Comment: @user1991965 From your code, it'd be easier to help you if you said what you want to do, instead of just showing the code. Rephrase your question saying, I want to do this and that with the files in this and that directory.

Comment: I changed the code (See above) it doesn't give any more error but it doesn't even rename the file intended

Comment: @user1991965 why do you have a here document being created? (what's the purpose of `<<EOF ... EOF`?)

Comment: please read from the top u might understand it better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you made it a bit clearer, I guess this is what you want:

- an associative array to map "MONTH NAME" to "MONTH NUMBER";
- rename a file from "TACOS_YYYY-month-dd__HH-MM-SS*.csv" to "TACOS_YYYYmmdd_HHMMSS.csv".

The solution in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A month
month["Jan"]=01
month["Feb"]=02
month["Mar"]=03
month["Apr"]=04
month["May"]=05
month["Jun"]=06
month["Jul"]=07
month["Aug"]=08
month["Sep"]=09
month["Oct"]=10
month["Nov"]=11
month["Dec"]=12

directory="YOUR/PATH/TACOS_"
for path in "${directory}"*; do

    path=${path#${directory}}
    newpath=${path:0:4}${month[${path:5:3}]}${path:9:2}
    newpath=${newpath}__$(tr -d '-' <<< ${path:13:8}).csv

    echo "${directory}${path}" "${directory}${newpath}" # Run this one first!!!
    # mv "YOUR/PATH/${path}" "YOUR/PATH/${newpath}"

done
```

This converts the string `path=TACOS_2013-Jan-22__00-50-00_UTC.csv` into `newpath=TACOS_20130122__005000.csv`, and renames the initial file `mv`'ing it to the new path constructed.

As in explanation, `bash` offers you associative arrays, that you **have to** declare prior to any operation using `declare -A assoc_array`.

In `bash` you can take string intervals, setting an `offset`, a `length`, and doing `${string:offset:length}`. Concatenation is performed by juxtaposition of strings, and assignments must have no spaces between `left_value=right_value`.

In addition, you have `tr` command, translating your string from `initial` to `initial_without_characters`, since the flag `-d` has been used. You may take a look at `man tr` for further reference.

**Edit:**

Since you don't have a more recent version of `bash`, you can use the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function month() {

    case $1 in
        "Jan") echo "01" ;;
        "Feb") echo "02" ;;
        "Mar") echo "03" ;;
        "Apr") echo "04" ;;
        "May") echo "05" ;;
        "Jun") echo "06" ;;
        "Jul") echo "07" ;;
        "Aug") echo "08" ;;
        "Sep") echo "09" ;;
        "Oct") echo "10" ;;
        "Nov") echo "11" ;;
        "Dec") echo "12" ;;
    esac

}

directory="YOUR/PATH/TACOS_"
for path in "${directory}"*; do

    path=${path#${directory}}
    newpath=${path:0:4}$(month ${path:5:3})${path:9:2}
    newpath=${newpath}__$(tr -d '-' <<< ${path:13:8}).csv

    echo "${directory}${path}" "${directory}${newpath}" # Run this one first!!!
    # mv "YOUR/PATH/${path}" "YOUR/PATH/${newpath}"

done
```

Comment: Sorry to disturb u again and again but i got the following error

mv: rename desktop/reports/Don/desktop/reports/Don/TACOS_* to desktop/reports/Don/desktop/rep12-/D__/TACOS_*.csv: No such file or directory

Comment: @user1991965 Sorry, just noticed I've put the `*` inside the double quotes, allowing bash not to perform the parameter expansion. Please, try it again.

Comment: now its giving me this error


mv: rename desktop/reports/Don/desktop/reports/Don/TACOS_2013-Jan-18__00-50-00_UTC.csv to desktop/reports/Don/desktop/rep12-/D__/TACOS_2.csv: No such file or directory

Comment: @user1991965 please, run the script with `echo`, instead of `mv`, so that you don't mess up with your files. The problem here is that the path is already being added, so you do not need to add it once again. I'll make an edit.

Comment: also the newpath constructed i want the format like the following 

TACOS_20130122_005000.csv and not TACOS_2013-01-22__005000.csv

Comment: i am replacing "YOUR/PATH/TACOS_" with "desktop/reports/Don/TACOS_"
should i do it everywhere this command is mentioned or only in the top one....Please see my BASH SCRIPT in the question asked (edited it)

Comment: I have considered that `"TACOS_"` would be present on the path, and only `"YOUR/PATH/"` would be given. I may edit with a more flexible solution if you want.

Comment: okay so after runnig the new script it gave me the following 
desktop/reports/Don/TACOS_2013-Jan-18__00-50-00_UTC.csv desktop/reports/Don/TACOS_20131218__005000.csv
but it didn't rename the file in the folder (Very sorry for disturbing you zoo much)

Comment: @user1991965 Yes, it shouldn't do so, as the line with the `mv` command is commented by the `#`. If you're sure the initial path and the path to which the file shall be moved are correct, just remove the `echo` line and the `#` from the beginning of the `mv` command.

Comment: one small thing if u see Jan is being replaced with 12 where it should be replace with 01 (if u want to see my script please look at the question)

Comment: Any month the file have this command converts it into 12 rather then 01 for Jan or 02 for Feb

Comment: @user1991965 Noticed it here: I thought associative arrays could be created directly, without initial declaration, but it does not work properly. You have to declare them prior to usage, as I point in the edit. Guess it works fine, now. Please, try it once again.

Comment: Got this error now

line 2: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
desktop/reports/Don/TACOS_2013-Jan-18__00-50-00_UTC.csv desktop/reports/Don/TACOS_20131218__005000.csv

Comment: @user1991965 What version of `bash` are you using? You can check it with `bash --version`.

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: @user1991965 Ah, that's it; bash associative arrays require version >= 4.0, so you don't have this feature available. What you can do is write a small function with a sequence of `case ... esac`, to replace the associative array. I'll post such function right away, just I've had my dinner (:

Comment: @user1991965 I guess there'll be no problem now; try it once more.

Comment: it is skipping the month now 

desktop/reports/Don/TACOS_2013-Jan-18__00-50-00_UTC.csv desktop/reports/Don/TACOS_201318__005000.csv

Comment: just one last question.... to rename i would have to replace echo with mv??? and if i have a file name for example TACOS_AA_NAME_ rather than just TACOS_ what would i have to change..... SORRY TO BOTHER U

Comment: @user1991965 haha, I'm way far from it ^^ I've edited the code, so that you may define the entire prefix of the files (both the directory and the beginning of the path). To really move the files, just remove the `#` from the front of the `mv` line, so that it gets executed. Finally, the script is way far from what I'd name flexible; the best to do in your case would be to extract each part you want with a regex, and then concatenate the parts into a new string. I guess it's a bit less hard coded now. (: